# Alternative way to template struct with static member function in cuda?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, cuda

In C++ I often use static functions encapsulated in template structs to be able to specify a function template at compile time allowing for various optimizations, e.g. inlining etc (btw, does this have a name?). Example (quite contrived, and there are probably errors but you get the point):

```
template <int dim>
struct ImplementationA {
    static float compute(float a) {
        // do stuff, e.g.
        return 2*pow(a,dim);
    }
};

template <int dim>
struct ImplementationB {
    static float compute(float a) {
        // do other stuff, e.g.
        return 3*pow(a,dim);
    }
};

template <template <int> class ImplT, int dim> class Test {
    void compute_stuff(float *dst, const float *src, int N) {
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            dst[i] = ImlT<dim>::compute(src[i]);
    }
};

void main() {
    float v1[100];
    float v2[100];

    Test<ImplementationB,3> t;
    t.compute_stuff(v2,v1,N);
}
```

However, if I want to do the same thing in CUDA with `compute` being a kernel, i.e. `__global__`, it is impossible since one cannot have a `static __global__` member function. What other possibilities do I have that offer the same minimal performance overhead? I use GCC 4.6 so some C++11 features are unavailable.

Comment: What about wrapping a C++11 static member function around a kernel function invokation?

Comment: @JackOLantern, Yes this was what I eventually ended up doing. Worked just fine, but I'm sure the solution of `jet45` would have worked as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a template class with implementation in `__device__` method and small template `__global__` function that just uses this class and calls the method:

```
template <int dim> class ImplementationA
{
public:
    // parameters
    float *dst;
    const float *src;
    int N;

    // implementation
    __device__ void compute()
    {
        float a = src[threadIdx.x];
        // ...
    }
};

// The same for ImplementationB

// global function
template <class Impl>
__global__ void compute(Impl impl)
{
    impl.compute();
}

// call
ImplementationA<3> impl;
impl.src = src;
compute<<<1, 32>>>(impl);
```

Comment: Yes this does the trick, but I still think the solution of @JackOLantern is more neat since for the user, i.e. the class using different Implementations, everything is hidden behind the struct.